# MySQLWorkbench doesn't run on Windows 8.1

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have downloaded the MySQLWorkbench from [this](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/) link.
After installing it the MySQLWorkbench.exe file doesn't open up for some reason. I'm running a Windows 8.1 OS.

Has anyone had any similar issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you read the section about require prerequisites?

[image]

The installer should also have given you a notice if something is missing. I recommend however to use the [MySQL Windows Installer](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/installer/) which gives you even more help with that.